Не получается установить библиотеку в python 3.11.9 на ubuntu
пытаюсь установить библиотеку aiogram версии 2.23.1 на ubuntu 24.04. версия python - 3.11.9, версия pip - 24.0
устанавливаю командой в терминале - pip3 install aiogram=="2.23.1"
пробовал все что возможно! ставил венв, пытался поставить через python wheel, все бесполезно
ниодна библиотека не устанавливается
ошибка:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/aiogram/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/aiogram/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram==2.23.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiogram==2.23.1
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


Ваш Питон собран без криптографии, которая нужна для SSL, который нужен чтобы скачивать пакеты с HTTPS сайтов. Или обновите Питон (не сложно), или доставьте криптографический пакет (сложно) или работайте с локальным хранилищем пакетов (много головной боли, его придётся заполнять руками, копирую пакеты с HTTPS сайтов).
